# build a project with python 3.5 while system python is 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and the default version of the python is 3.8. I installed python 3.5 and gcc-5 myself as they were needed for building a project.

When I use `python3.5 setup.py build develop` it gives a silly error (i.e., `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`).

Answer (score 1):

When you're using 2 versions of Python, you have to be careful where the packages are installed. In this case, I would make sure `numpy` is installed on Python 3.5. You should be using the `pip` that comes with 3.5 NOT 3.8 otherwise `numpy` will be installed on python 3.8. Something like `pip3.5 install numpy` might fix your issue (if `pip` is labeled that way, if not find the install folder and directly reference the pip executable like `path/to/pip3.5 install numpy`).